# Is there a way to UnDim Variable?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm just wondering if there is a possibility to un-dim a variable.

Imagine this is my #include file that I'm using in ASP page

```
Dim MyVar
MyVar = "Hello World"
Response.write(MyVar)
'From now on I can not use Dim MyVar anymore as it throws an error
'I have tried
MyVar = Nothing
Set MyVar = Nothing
'But again, when you do
Dim MyVar
'It throws an error.
```

The reason for this is that I cannot use the same #INCLUDE file more than once per page. And yes, I do like using Option Explicit as it helps me to keep my code cleaner.

*) Edited: I see that it's not as clear as I wanted.

Imagine this is a "include.asp"

```
<%
Dim A
A=1
Response.Cookie("beer")=A
%>
```

Now the asp page:

```
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->
<%
'Now: I do not see whats in include above and I want to use variable A
Dim A
'And I get an error
'I also cannot use the same include again:
%>
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->
```

Do you see my point? If I would be able to UNDIM the A variable at the end of the Include, the problem would be solved.

Comment: I would suggest you don't try to do this as it would give different meaning to MyVar at the same scope. Why don't you just reuse MyVar after setting it to Nothing. e.g. `MyVar = "Hello World2"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no way to "UnDim" a variable. Luckily you also don't need that.

Whenever you try to declare a variable twice in the same scope, you're already making a mistake. Consider it as helpful that the runtime does not let you.

The solution:

- Don't work with global variables. Use functions, declare your variables there.
- Don't include the same file more than once.

Comment: 3. Declare variables explicitly `Private` or `Public` in a module, the intention is much clearer that way than using `Dim`. 4. Use classes to create objects if you want to keep state outside functions.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos `Private` and `Public` only work in classes in VBScript. There are no modules, that's VBA.

Comment: If you use `Windows Scripting Files` (.WSF) or `HTML Applications` (.HTA) you include scripts like `<script language='VBScript' src='script2.vbs' />`. I called it a module which is probably not the right term, but `private` and `public` are working as you would expect from a private and public declaration; not only inside classes.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Ah, that's nice... Didn't know that until now. So I guess that's also true for ASP's `<script runat="server" src="...">`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tomalak - I'm really not sure why you would need (or want) to include the same file twice (?)

It does seem to be a bad design philosophy, better to perhaps encapsulate the routines in the include file as functions or subroutines that can be called - no need to include twice.

Also, whilst you cannot undim, you can redim, but I don't want to encourage bad practices, given what you seem to be wanting to do.

You could use something like this instead of all that:

Include.asp:

```
 <%
 Function SetCookie(scVar, scVal)
     Response.cookie (scVar) = scVal
 End Function
 %>
```

The asp page:

```
 <!--#include file="include.asp"-->
<%
Dim A
A=1
SetCookie "Beer", A

A=1 ' This is kind of redundant in this code.

SetCookie "Beer", A
%>
```

---

However if you did want to use globals, and persist with including twice, you could do it this way by adding another include for globals.

Globals.asp:

```
 <%
 Dim globalVarA
 ...other global stuff here....
 %>
```

Include.asp:

```
<%
globalVarA=1
Response.Cookie("beer")=globalVarA
%>
```

Now the asp page:

```
<!--#include file="globals.asp"-->
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->
<%
Dim A
A=....something......
%>
<!--#include file="include.asp"-->
```

Comment: There's a certain chance that the OP is trying to use ASP include files like IIS server-side-includes (`SSI`). It would still be wrong but it would explain why he's including things more than once.