# Is wsh a reserved word in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

On Windows 7, I get an error for the following line in my VBScript:

```
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid
>   property assignment: 'wsh'

Using any name other than `wsh` works.

I scoured the web for information, but the pages for reserved keywords do not reference any mention of `wsh`.

I run the above script using the *cscript* command in the *CMD* processor.

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION WAS ANSWERED:**

Declaring the variable as `Dim wsh` overrides its keyword status, allowing its use in the script.  Came across this information after posting the question, here: http://forums.devshed.com/visual-basic-programming-52/bizzare-finding-username-918597.html

Comment: Yes. `wsh` is a builtin alias for the [`WScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31.aspx) object.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I can't find that documented anywhere.  This is a good question.  I've never come across `wsh` before in all my years.

Comment: @rory.ap I don't think it's documented anywhere (at least I haven't seen any documentation menioning it). I think I learned about it in the visualbasicscript.com forums a couple years back.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers -- well, it's documented here, now, to some degree then.  Although it could use an official answer.

Comment: @rory.ap Your request is my command. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`wsh` is a builtin alias for the [`WScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31.aspx) object, allowing you to write

```
wsh.Echo "foo"
wsh.StdErr.WriteLine "bar"
wsh.Quit 42
```

instead of

```
WScript.Echo "foo"
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "bar"
WScript.Quit 42
```

To my knowledge this isn't covered by the documentation, though.

---

**Edit:** Apparently you can work around the issue by defining `wsh` as a variable before using it:

```
Dim wsh
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

However, note that doing so will completely mask the original identifier, i.e. you won't be able to get the original behavior back without leaving the context in which the variable was defined (which in case of global variables means restarting the interpreter), because you [can't un-dim a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361561/1630171).